# Is the Xbox Elite controller allowed in competitive Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I [read on Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2019/7/27/8933240/fortnite-world-cup-winners-results-controller-wolfiez) that a Scuf Vantage is allowed for competitive events... what about the Elite controller?

Answer (score -1):

The only mention of controllers in this [unofficial summary](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortniteCompetitive/comments/c5xfxx/fortnite_world_cup_rule_book_shortened/) of the rulebook is that stick toppers (i.e. KontrolFreeks) are not allowed.

[2019 Online qualifier rulebook](https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Fortnite+Esports%2Fevents%2Fworld-cup%2Fworldcup-landing%2FRules%2FWorld-Cup-Online-Opens-Official-Rules-85fdb9049cde7fa021cb81126e25d24ded69733a.pdf)

[2019 World Cup Finals Rules](https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Fortnite+Esports%2Fevents%2Fworld-cup%2Fworldcup-landing%2FRules%2FFinalsRules%2FFinal-World-Cup-Finals-Official-Rules-NYC-a35102d1048db2030831f39c1be111a409b2cbb1.pdf) -- apparently Epic would provide Elite controllers upon request (did a "find" on "Elite")